# Как правильно посмотреть сколько нужно памяти для выполнения php скрипта?

Tags: php

Всем привет.
Использую yandex-parse.
При запуске на сервере, выбивает ошибку

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 482349056) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /YmlParser.php on line 155
>   PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Out of memory (allocated 482349056) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)'

Запускаю этот скрипт на локалке с функцией [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.memory-get-usage.php)
После выполнения скрипта возвращает

> 628736 KB

На сервере должно хватать, так как там гиг.
Надеюсь, понятно объяснил, благодарю за помощь.

Comment: `482349056` чем вам не объем использованной под задачу памяти? а сколько _нужно_ будет в действительности, никто не скажет, пока скрипт не выполнится

Comment: @teran оке, это значит 0.4 гигабайта ОЗУ, на сервере Гиг, но все равно вибвает такую ошибку, не могли бы подсказать, почему?

Comment: начните с проверки `memory_limit` в `php.ini`

Comment: @teran забыл сказать, поставил -1 у memory_limit :D
Сейчас проверил через команду FREE на сервере, вывело total(1040330752), free(491642880). Как я понимаю слишком мало свободной памяти для выполнения этого скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сервере может и 1ГБ, но со всеми активными процессами будет всегда меньше чем указано.

Никакие проверки memory_limit в php.ini не помогут. Вы получаете ошибку **PHP Fatal error: Out of memory**, а не более общую **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ...**, что означает что система просто не может выделить больше памяти, чем у нее доступно.

Для выполнения данного скрипта просто недостаточно памяти, вам нужно увеличить обьем доступной памяти или поменять библиотеку, которая более экономично бы использовала оперативную память, если это конечно возможно в рамках реализуемой вами задачи.

Comment: я вот как раз пытался вспомнить какие сообщение и в каком случае показываются, но не вспомнил (: поэтому предложил проверить лимит :)

Comment: Благодарю все, помогли, увеличу память до 2гб)

Comment: @teran Я честно говоря, и сам сразу начал писать в ответе 'проверьте memory_limit', но вчитался в ошибку и вспомнил всю боль и что там разные сообщения для разных случаев :)